# regexReplace using select

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2012

I want to use a regular expression to remove special characters (!, ", #, $,%, &, /. (,), =,?, |) from a table

```
SELECT
  '|R!$#&2-_D%2' as Original, 
  UPPER
  (
    REPLACE
    (
      ( MDS_Demo.mdq.regexReplace
        ('|R!2- _D%2',
         '[!|”#$%&/()=?»«;,:._]', '', 0
        )
      )
    , '  ', ' '
    ) 
  ) as Correct
```

The list of characters and words to remove identified is in a table, so I wanted to replace the list of character identified in the expression and used a select to a table where is listed all special character to removed.

```
SELECT
  '|R!$#&2-_D%2' as Original, 
  UPPER(REPLACE((MDS_Demo.mdq.regexReplace('|R!2- _D%2',
    < SELECT SPECIAL_CHARACTERS FROM TABLE01 >
    , '', 0)), '  ', ' ') ) as Correct
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Does it even support RegExp?

Comment: Yes, i'm using SQL Server 2012. The first example that i had post it work, now i wna't to used a table where i had defined the special charcaters and words to removed

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can replace any string expression with a `(SELECT ...)`

i.e. `SELECT ltrim( (SELECT '  trimmed') ) as test` works here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8222f/4

.. so where you have your `< SELECT SPECIAL_CHARACTERS FROM TABLE01 >` just put the required SELECT inside brackets and you're good to go?